# InfoPath People picker doesn't show up

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, people-picker

I have a dropdown menu with **a, b,** and **c** values.
Also, I have a People Picker in a Section and the section has formatting rules to it.
When **a** is selected from the dropdown menu the section shows up, but in Internet Explorer the people picker doesn't show up. **In chrome it does.**
Please help me.

If I delete the rules to the section, the people picker shows up on IE too.

Answer (score 1):

Put this in a content editor linked from the page:

```
<script language="javascript">
/* IE11 Fix for SP2010 */
if (typeof(UserAgentInfo) != 'undefined' && !window.addEventListener) 
{
    UserAgentInfo.strBrowser=1; 
} 
</script>
```